# How do I declare an Name in XSD from XML

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am quite new to writing XSD Schemas and I was just wondering for a bit of help. When I'm checking my XSD's formatting I get the error

```
Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'interface'., Line '1', Column '32'.
```

I can't seem to understand how I declare the name of the interface.
Below is the XML code and below that is the XSD code I have wrote so far.

If anyone has any other pointers or knowledge on how I'd look at doing imports and retunrs I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Your XSD is completely barren.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to get rid of that error first. Or do I need more XSD to declare the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="interface">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="package"/>
        <xs:element ref="extends"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="import"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="abstract_method"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="package" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="extends">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="from"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="from" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="import" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="abstract_method">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="access_level"/>
        <xs:element ref="arguments"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="throws"/>
        <xs:element ref="return"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="access_level" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="arguments">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="parameter"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="parameter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:NCName">
          <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="throws">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="exception"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="exception" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="return" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @EthanBeardsley. good to hear that it is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: @EthanBeardsley, what happened? All of a sudden, you unmarked it as Answer?